# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Call to undefined function redirect()

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

```
15.     // Check Session Login
16.      if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
17.         redirect(site_url('auth/login'));
18.      }
19.   }
20.
21.    function index(){
22.       redirect(site_url('home/dashboard'));
23.    }
```

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Call to undefined function redirect()
>   Line Number: 17

Comment: The error is fairly obvious - your program doesn't contain a function called "redirect". Where do you believe this function is coming from?

Comment: because before I upload to hosting it works normally, when I upload an error occurs as follows

Comment: @ImamMuharom I would guess you either forgot to upload part of the project (or something it depends on), or put it in the wrong folder so it wasn't included properly.

Comment: What is the CI version?

Comment: @ADyson whereas at the time of uploading the project, I made it into a zip file and then extracted on the hosting :D

Comment: @mickmackusa my CI version 3.0.5 :D

Comment: @ImamMuharom ok but that doesn't prove anything by itself. The computer is not lying to you - that function is definitely missing. So please double-check everything you uploaded. In particular you should check the path that mickmackusa mentioned, which was helpful, so you know precisely where the function _should_ be located.

Comment: @ADyson okay thanks for the advice, after I opened the project, the file 'auth/login' it was already there but the error message remained like that  :D hehee

Comment: I can't quite tell if you're saying it's fixed or not

Comment: This page must not be reopened in its current state because it would need to be instantly reclosed as `Off-topic: Cannot Reproduce`.

Comment: @Imam where is this being called? In a Controller method? View? Model?